# How to export Silverlight 3.0 ListBox contents to Excel & Word?

Tags: silverlight, export-to-excel

The ListBox contains multiple ListBoxes which inturn contain many ListBoxItems. The top level ListBox does not have a ItemsSource collection bound to it, rather the child ListBoxes have ListBoxItems that are bound to individual properties in the VM. Is there a way to just dump the ListBox "contents" to an Excel file, may be by converting them to an XML format first??

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to translate [this post on exporting a datagrid to Excel](http://www.rshelby.com/post/exporting-data-from-silverilght-datagrid-to-excel.aspx) to your list box scenario. In your case you will need to walk the control tree to find the children of each child (probably in a recursive manner) and then render it to Excel using xml.